# MSAL and Android mobile apps: library version mismatch

Tags: android, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Current version of MSAL library uses an old Android CustomTabs library (23.3.0) and doesn’t support the more recent one (25.3.1) that we are using in the app.
Is there any workaround for this issue?
PS: yes, we know, MSAL is in preview phase, but it is declared as go-live

Comment: So what is the current state? The 1.1.0 is not available via NuGet, marked as alpha and requires download of code and build locally. Is this version "go live" ready?

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed the lateast **dev** version of MSAL on GitHub, it shows that MSAL has supported the [`25.3.1`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/blob/dev/msal/build.gradle#L107) version of Android CustomTabs library.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

So if you don't want to downgrade the old version [`25.1.0`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/blob/v0.1.1/msal/build.gradle#L106) for using the latest MSAL `0.1.1`/`0.1.0`, the only solution is that building the MSAL latest dev version and use it in your project.

Comment: I believe the question about Xamarin (MSAL .NET) not Android.